# Characterization of tempered distributions from tempered sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, schwartz-distributions, infinite-sequences, generalized-functions, tempered-distributions

Let $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of compactly supported and infinitely smooth functions for its usual topology. Let
$\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ be the topological dual of  $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. the space of Schwartz' distributions. We also consider the space of smooth and rapidly decaying functions $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and its dual, the space $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R})$ of tempered distributions.

By analogy, we define the space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{Z})$ of rapidly decaying sequences and its dual, the space $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{Z})$ of *tempered sequences* (i.e. sequences that are bounded by some polynomial).

I am wondering if the following characterization is correct.

**Conjecture:** A distribution $f \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ is tempered if and only if, for any $\varphi \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, the sequence $(\langle f, \varphi (\cdot - k) \rangle)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{Z})$.

I could prove the direct implication, but not the other one. And I could also not provide a counterexample. Any insight is welcome.